# How Can I Detect If One Div Is Outside Another Div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, mouseover

I am making a game and I am using div's instead of canvas.rect's and I want one div to always be inside of another div. I ran into this problem when I made a test script that looked like this.

```js
        var mousex, mousey;
          function mousepos(e){
            mousex = e.clientX;
            mousey = e.clientY;
            document.getElementById("xy").innerText = mousex + " , " + mousey;
          }
          function testdiv(){
            document.getElementById("testdiv").style.left = mousex;
            document.getElementById("testdiv").style.top = mousey;
            setTimeout(testdiv, 30);
          }
```

```css
          #city{
            border: 1px dotted white;
            background-color: lightgreen;
            height: 500;
            width: 500;
            resize: both;
            overflow: hidden;
            max-height: 500px;
            max-width: 500px;
            min-height: 100px;
            min-width: 100px;
          }
          #xy{
            color: white;
          }
          #testdiv{
            background-color: white;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
          }
          #body{
            background-color: black;
          }
```

```html
    <body id="body" onload="testdiv()">
        <center>
          <div id="city" onmousemove="mousepos(event);">
            <div id="testdiv"></div>
          </div>
          <p id="xy"></p>
        </center>
     </body>
```

The code detects your mouse X and mouse Y when your mouse is over the big green div, then it puts the white div's left corner on your mouse X and mouse Y. My problem is that when my mouse is draging the white div down or right, I can drag it off of the green div.

Is there a way I could fix this problem?

Comment: you can call Element.getBoundingClientRect() on parent element and check if mousex/mousey is bigger than left/top and less then width/height

Comment: https://codepen.io/piotrazsko/pen/VrrZBq

Comment: I do not recommend use recursion. For high performance use a  loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a simple, more understandable way to do this.

I created a variables for the testdiv's width, height, x, y, x offset from 
mouse, and y offset from mouse.

```
var divw = 50;
var divh = 50;

var divofx = 25;
var divofy = 25;
```

Then I made a variable for the city divs width.

```
var cityw = 500;
```

Then, I used screen.width / 2 to find the center of the screen.

```
var centerx = screen.width / 2;
```

Then, I made the size of the testdiv changeable at any time by putting the code below into the main function :

```
document.getElementById("testdiv").style.width = divw;
document.getElementById("testdiv").style.height = divh;
```

Then I used the width variable to find the edges of the city div.

Then, based off of the edges, I made some simple collision detecting if statements. I also did not need to change the Y mutch since it pretty mutch stays the same.

```
        if(mousex + divw > centerx + (cityw / 2)){
          mousex = centerx + (cityw / 2) - divw;
        }
        else{
          document.getElementById("testdiv").style.left = mousex;
        }
        if(mousey > (cityw - divh) + 10){
          mousey = (cityw - divh) + 10;
        }
        else{
          document.getElementById("testdiv").style.top = mousey;
        }
        if(mousex < centerx - cityw / 2){
          mousex = centerx - cityw / 2;
        }
        if(mousey < 8){
          mousey = 8;
        }
        setTimeout(testdiv, 1);
```

Now the whole program looks like:

```
<html>

  <head>

    <style>

      #city{
        border: 1px dotted white;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        height: 500;
        width: 500;
        overflow: none;
        max-height: 500px;
        max-width: 500px;
        min-height: 100px;
        min-width: 100px;
      }
      #xy{
        color: white;
      }
      #testdiv{
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }
      #body{
        background-color: black;
      }

    </style>
    <script>

    var mousex, mousey;
    var divw = 50;
    var divh = 50;
    var divofx = 25;
    var divofy = 25;
    var cityw = 500;

      function mousepos(e){
        mousex = e.clientX - divofx;
        mousey = e.clientY - divofy;
        document.getElementById("xy").innerText = mousex + " , " + mousey;
      }

      function testdiv(){
        var centerx = screen.width / 2;

        document.getElementById("city").style.width = cityw;
        document.getElementById("testdiv").style.width = divw;
        document.getElementById("testdiv").style.height = divh;

        if(mousex + divw > centerx + (cityw / 2)){
          mousex = centerx + (cityw / 2) - divw;
        }
        else{
          document.getElementById("testdiv").style.left = mousex;
        }
        if(mousey > (cityw - divh) + 10){
          mousey = (cityw - divh) + 10;
        }
        else{
          document.getElementById("testdiv").style.top = mousey;
        }
        if(mousex < centerx - cityw / 2){
          mousex = centerx - cityw / 2;
        }
        if(mousey < 8){
          mousey = 8;
        }
        setTimeout(testdiv, 1);
      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body id="body" onload="testdiv()" onmousemove="mousepos(event);">

    <center>
      <div id="city" onmousemove="mousepos(event);">
        <div id="testdiv"></div>
      </div>

      <p id="xy"></p>
    </center>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no supported parent selectors in the current JS.

You could either use Jquery or CSS, I am listing both Javascript options, and CSS options

1. Option 1: `$("a.active").parents('li').css("property", "value");`
2. Option 2: [Sibling Combination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to match any `ParentElement`
   element that is preceded by an `ChildElement` element.

   `// Just change the parent and child elemets below
   ParentElement ~ ChildElement {
       property: value;
   }`

Comment: I'd prefer not to use jQuery, so I can't use this option. Plus I do not understand the second option that you provided. Could you clarify?

Comment: You could use the `css` to select the div, using the div relationship Iisted above.. if you click on the link... you will see more examples

Answer (score 0):

You can make a check before changing the child div position, if its new position is outside of where you want it to be, you can skip it.

Something like:

```
if (mouse.x > parent_div_width){
    return;
}
else {
   child_div_Xpos = mouse.x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to try this code:

```
  var mousex, mousey;

function mousepos(e) {
    mousex = e.clientX;
    mousey = e.clientY;
    document.getElementById("xy").innerText = mousex + " , " + mousey;
}
var coordCity = document.getElementById("city").getBoundingClientRect();
var elem = document.getElementById("testdiv");
let i = 0

function testdiv() {
    elem.style.left = mousex + 'px';
    elem.style.top = mousey + 'px';
    var coord = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(coord.left < coordCity.left ||
      coord.right > coordCity.right ||
      coord.bottom > coordCity.bottom || 
      coord.top < coordCity.top) {
      console.log('rect is out');
    };
    i++;
    if(i === 100) {
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(testdiv, 50);
}
```

And you need add in css px to value of width and height:

```
#city{
            border: 1px dotted white;
            background-color: lightgreen;
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            resize: both;
            overflow: hidden;
            max-height: 500px;
            max-width: 500px;
            min-height: 100px;
            min-width: 100px;
          }
```

And always save youre nodes to variable, because it does youre code faster, I use variable i  for stop test. You can use another solution. 
I created next app:
https://codepen.io/piotrazsko/pen/VrrZBq

Comment: what role does the "let i = 0" and the "if(i === 100){return;" play?

Comment: this is return from testdiv function